# Detecting fast moving balls in low resolution image

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection

I'm working on a automatic tennis video editor for mobile phones and home-recorded videos, and I'm currently stuck trying to detect a fast moving ball in a low resolution image.

I've tried a bunch of approaches:

1. I calculate the temporal delta between the current frame and the previous frame, and then pick the contours in the current frame that intersect with the temporal delta image (current frame - previous frame). This leaves me with contours of players body parts and the ball contour.
2. I filter the contours by size, so I only get contours that could belong to a ball (or a player's head, or the tip of his shoe, etc)
3. I can't really filter by color, as a badly illuminated ball becomes grey, and there are courts of all colors (grey, blue, red) and the ball ends up having a color close to that of the court or a player's head, in many cases
4. Can't filter by roundness as players and rackets also have round parts which wont get filtered (and blurry balls sometimes do not look round)
5. Feature extraction seems to have a hard time with low resolution images, but I might have applied it badly, as I don't have a lot of knowledge in the domain. I tried SURF and SIFT on greyscale versions of my images
6. I know the ball (if present), will be at the center of the image, surrounded by something else (easy cases are a plain color, but sometimes it goes over the court lines, or the player's rackets)
7. I've tried training classifiers from my samples, either from feature vectors or the original images themselves, and the most I got was 95% precision, which is still low for my application (I'd say I get better precision by filtering the points by neighbourhood color on my own)

So I'm kinda stuck now, wondering what other technique I could use to eliminate the false positives. The technique that had the most success was to check the neighbourhood of the ball to see if it has a different color from the ball, but the problem is this doesn't filter the false positives (a player head in the back of the court has about the size of a ball in front of the court, and also has a different color from its neighbourhood, so it is detected as a false positive)

I can't embed images to this topic, but all my sample images are available at:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s9m6xq50g4ehdw1/AABXnqkBYlhYeNXOwpZuKBD6a?dl=0

Comment: I can say it is nothing, but very hard to implement and guarantee satisfying accuracy. You need to very complex algorithms to achieve, maybe you will need to Kalman Filter algorithm as well, to track the object when it is not recognizable.

Comment: I assume these sample images are cutouts? You realize that re-encoding as jpeg further decreases the quality, right?

Comment: @Nyerguds indeed, they are cutouts that I recover from a preprocessing algorithm that selects ball candidates. I hadn't thought about the quality loss from jpeg compression, but from what I see it doesn't change much from the uncompressed version, not enough to justify an algorithm not being able to recognize the ball in it